# Does meshlab supports re-meshing based on resolution (i.e. 1mm)?

Tags: meshlab

Does meshlab supports re-meshing based on resolution (i.e. 1mm)?
When I open 3D data with color texture captured with Structure Sensor in Skanetct,
I can export ply with '1mm' option with vertex Color(VC), which preserves texture pretty well.

When convert the data scanned with 3rd party app (itseez3D), the raw .ply data looks pretty well. But when I apply filter 'texture to vertex color', the texture goes very bad. I guess it's due to not enough vertex, right?

Is there any way in MeshLab to do something like Skanect export (divide vertex if necessary and apply texture color to vertex while keep it's quality as best as possible).
I need real-world metric for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the various subdivision surfaces algorithms (that all include a edge threshold length as a parameter) or the *Isotropic Explicit Remeshing* that has a "target length" parameter. All of them allow you to get a more complex mesh where vertexes are as dense as needed.